# Table Calendar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How select years on Table Calendar flutter

```
TableCalendar(
          headerStyle: const HeaderStyle(
              formatButtonVisible: false, titleCentered: true),
          firstDay: DateTime.utc(2010, 10, 16),
          lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 3, 14),
          focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
          onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
            controllerTtl.text = selectedDay.toString().substring(0, 10);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
```

Toggle the year selection option in Table Calendar

Answer (score 0):

I think in [TableCalendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) package there is no default way to select and change the year. But you can do these steps to select year in table calendar.

1. Create a `stateful widget`
2. Define a `focusedDay` (type DateTime) state
3. Use the `onHeaderTapped` function in TableCalendar
4. Show a `date picker` to select date from the user
5. Assign the selected date to focusedDay inside `setState`

`

```
TableCalendar(
   headerStyle: const HeaderStyle(
      formatButtonVisible: false,
      titleCentered: true,
   ),
   firstDay: DateTime.utc(2010, 10, 16),
   lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 3, 14),
   focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
   onHeaderTapped: (focusedDay) {
      // 1. show date picker
      // 2. update the focusedDay state with the selected date (from date picker)
   },
),
```